# Topological space not being metrizable.

Tags: general-topology, metrizability

**Question**: Consider $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ with the topology $\mathcal{T} = \{U \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{2} : \mathbb{R}^{2} \setminus U \text{ is countable }\} \cup \{\emptyset\}$. Suppose that there is a metric $\rho$ inducing the topology $\mathcal{T}$. Choose two distinct points $x$ and $y$ and suppose that $\rho(x, y) = d$. Consider the open balls of radius $d/3$ centered at $x$ and $y$. Prove that the intersection of these balls is not empty, and that this contradicts the triangle inequality property of a metric.

**My attempt**: We suppose that the metric $\rho$ induces the topology $\mathcal{T}$ on $\mathbb{R}^{2}$. Then, by definition the collection of all $d$-balls $B(x, d)$ for $d > 0$ and $x \in \mathbb{R}^{2}$ is a basis for the topology $\mathcal{T}$. In particular, the balls $B(x, d/3)$ and $B(y, d/3)$ are also basis elements. By definition basis elements are also elements of the topology. By the definition of the topology, this means that $\mathbb{R}^{2} \setminus B(x, d/3)$ and $\mathbb{R}^{2} \setminus B(y, d/3)$ are countable. Then, also the union $\mathbb{R}^{2} \setminus B(x, d/3) \cup \mathbb{R}^{2} \setminus B(y, d/3)$ is countable. Now, since $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ is uncountable, it follows that the complement $\mathbb{R}^{2} \setminus (\mathbb{R}^{2} \setminus B(x, d/3)) \cup (\mathbb{R}^{2} \setminus B(y, d/3)) = B(x, d/3) \cap B(y, d/3)$ is uncountable, and thus non-empty. Now we may take a $z \in B(x, d/3) \cap B(y, d/3)$. Then $\rho(x, z) < d/3$ and $\rho(y, z) < d/3$. Since we assumed that $\rho(x, y) = d$, it follows that $d(x, y) = d > d(x, z) + d(z, y) = 2d/3$, contradicting the triangle inequality of a metric.

It follows directly that the topological space $(\mathbb{R}^{2}, \mathcal{T})$ is not metrizable, as there is no metric inducing $\mathcal{T}$.

My main concern of my proof is whether the construction I made of $B(x, d/3) \cap B(y, d/3)$ is the correct way of doing it. If anybody can help me out or give suggestions I would gladly appreciate that!

Comment: This looks exactly right to me! Nice work. To be very pedantic, you might briefly mention explicitly that the balls are not empty. An alternative way to present the argument would be to prove a lemma "if $U$ and $V$ are non-empty and open wrt $\mathcal T$, then their intersection is non-empty" (mostly to save having to write out $B(x, \tfrac d3)$ so many times!)

Comment: Thank you for your comment @IzaakvanDongen. I have one more question about the lemma you stated, that is generally not true right? Or did you specifically mean that for the case of this question.

Comment: Yes indeed that lemma is not true in full generality - what I wrote refers only to $\mathcal  T$, which is defined in this question in terms of $\Bbb R^2$. In general this construction is called "the co-countable topology". A lemma that does hold in general is "if $X$ is uncountable, then the intersection of non-empty open sets in the co-countable topology on $X$ is non-empty". If you wanted to generalise further, a similar fact is still true about "co-$\kappa$ spaces of cardinality at least $\kappa$", but that's getting a bit carried away :)

Comment: That is very interesting. Thanks a lot for your comments.

Comment: One issue in your proof as stated is that $x, y, d$ are defined in the question. But at the start of your proof, you use $x$ and $d$ to mean something else. However, later in the proof, you expect $x$ and $d$ to have the definitions assigned in the question again. This is a very bad mathematical habit that will trip you up if you do not break yourself of it. Do not use the same variable to mean two different things within the same context. There are lots of other choices for variable names.

Comment: You are right @PaulSinclair. Thank you for your feedback.